# Error control wants to select step smaller than minimum allowed

Tags: drake

I'm getting the following error when I run my simulation

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Error control wants to select step smaller than minimum allowed (1e-14)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying Russ's answer from piazza here

> you probably have something in your dynamics that is returning inf?  (which means the simulator is trying to obtain an impossible accuracy).
>
> you can put the simulator into [fixed step mode](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1_integrator_base.html#a53f8dced020f4fa9c3ccfc2eb6982a86) to power through, but you'll just be simulating nonsense.  i think you need to find the source of the numerical blow-up.